# How do I convert date intervals to date index in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas df like this:

```
color   start           end
red     01/01/1980  31/12/1982
blue    01/01/1983  31/12/1988
blue    01/01/1989  31/12/1995
red     01/01/1996  31/12/1997
blue    01/01/1998  31/12/1999
red     01/01/2000  31/12/2004
```

How do I transform the date intervals into an index, keeping only the year? Like this:

```
1980    red
1981    red
1982    red
1983    blue
1984    blue
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `set_index` and `reindex`, and `ffill` forward filling missing values, you can get

```
In [319]: dff = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['start']).dt.year)['color']

In [320]: dff
Out[320]:
start
1980     red
1983    blue
1989    blue
1996     red
1998    blue
2000     red
Name: color, dtype: object
```

Then `reindex` from date ranges and forward `ffill` missing values.

```
In [321]: dff.reindex(range(dff.index.min(), dff.index.max()+1)).ffill()
Out[321]:
start
1980     red
1981     red
1982     red
1983    blue
1984    blue
1985    blue
1986    blue
1987    blue
1988    blue
1989    blue
1990    blue
1991    blue
1992    blue
1993    blue
1994    blue
1995    blue
1996     red
1997     red
1998    blue
1999    blue
2000     red
Name: color, dtype: object
```

Comment: @John Galt - One  thing though, this way I won't get the years 2001, 2002, 2003 and 2004, which should all be 'red'.

Comment: You could get min from start column and max from end column then.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your your date columns are datetime objects (you can convert them if not using `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`. Otherwise it's simply:

```
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df2 = df.set_index(['Year'])
```

Comment: Thing is that I don't have a 'Date' column, but rather 'start' and 'end'.